# Recursivly format object

Tags: php, recursion

i have an object in this format that can be infinately deep.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [condition] => AND
    [rules] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => app
                    [field] => app
                    [type] => string
                    [operator] => equal
                    [value] => files_sharing
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => deviceType
                    [field] => deviceType
                    [type] => string
                    [input] => select
                    [operator] => equal
                    [value] => android
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => userGroup
                    [field] => userGroup
                    [type] => string
                    [operator] => equal
                    [value] => admin
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [condition] => AND
                    [rules] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => userGroup
                                    [field] => userGroup
                                    [type] => string
                                    [operator] => equal
                                    [value] => group
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => time
                                    [field] => time
                                    [type] => time
                                    [input] => text
                                    [operator] => between
                                    [value] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 12:30 am -0500
                                            [1] => 06:00 am -0500
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => request
                                    [field] => request
                                    [type] => string
                                    [input] => select
                                    [operator] => equal
                                    [value] => post
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The format im trying to get it into is

```
array(
0 => array(
'condition' => 'and',
'rules' => array({RULESHERE})
),
1 => array(
'condition' => 'and',
'rules' => array({RULES HERE})
),
);
```

What i have at the moment is this but it is failing hardcore.

```
Public function loop(obj) {
    // First we get the condition
            $this->stack[$this->stackCounter]['condition'] = $obj->condition;
            $this->stack[$this->stackCounter]['rules'] = array();

            foreach ($obj as $rule) {
                if (isset($rule->condition)) {
                    $this->loop($rule);
                } else {
                    array_push($this->stack[$this->stackCounter]['rules'], $rule);
    //                      $this->evalCondition($rule);
                }
            }
            $this->stackCounter++;
        }
}
```

Could someone please lend an idiot a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($obj->rules as $rule) {
```

Stack counter should be passed as parameter to make it local. Otherwise the stack counter will change globally as soon as you go into a branch loop and come back to iterate the next rules. So the code looks like this:

```
public function loop($obj, $stackCounter)
{
    $this->stack[$stackCounter]['condition'] = $obj->condition;
    $this->stack[$stackCounter]['rules'] = array();

    foreach ($obj->rules as $rule) {
        if (isset($rule->condition)) {
            $this->loop($rule, $stackCounter + 1);
        } else {
            array_push($this->stack[$stackCounter]['rules'], $rule);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew it was something stupid, that works for the nested rules but not the first set of rules and condiion...

Comment: could you update your intended output to include the 4th element where you have a nested condition?

Comment: @ClarkT. Is the stack counter set to 0 before starting the loop?

Comment: @ClarkT. See edited answer for new suggestion for the stack counter.